# How to remove a user from SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

If I open SQL Server 2014 Management Studio GUI and connect to my database, I can expand the database > Security > Logins to see the list of users that can login.

I'm trying to find out the SQL statement that I can use to remove one of those users (I need an automated solution).

I've tried

```
drop login 'BUILTIN\Users'

delete from master..syslogins where loginname = 'BUILTIN\Users'

drop user 'BUILTIN\Users'
```

from the drop commands, I get the error

> Incorrect syntax near 'BUILTIN\Users'

and the delete throws

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the quotes but brackets instead.

```
DROP LOGIN [BUILTIN\Users]
```